# Equations defining span of vectors

Tags: vectors

v1 = (1,-2,t), v2 = (t,t<sup>2</sup>,t<sup>2</sup>).
For each fixed t, give equations defining the span of v1 and v2.

Could someone please help answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the coordinates of $w:=v_1\times v_2$. 
If that's not zero, then your equation for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ will be
$$w_1x_1+w_2x_2+w_3x_3=0$$
since $x\in\mathrm{span}(v_1, v_2)\ \iff \ x\perp w\ \iff \ \langle w,x\rangle=0$.

Comment: The product will be zero if $t\in\{0,-2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate a basis for the kernel of the matrix which row vectors are $v_1$ and $v_2$.  I get $(-2,-1,0)^t$ and $(0,0,1)^t$ for $t=0$, hence in this case the span is given by the equations $-2x-y=0$ and $z=0$; for $t=-2$ I get $x-2y=0$ and $2x+z=0$.

Now if $\notin\{0,-2\}$ I found the equation $tx+ty-z=0$.